# jQuery - For each class within another class

Tags: jquery

**Aim:** Get each value for each object from the classes option1, 2 and 3 OR whether it is possible to use $(this) with an each() function to only refer to the classes within the already selected object?

*Edit/Note: My actual code dynamically created/adds the div tags*

**Example HTML:**

```
<div class="object">
    <div class="object-title">Object Title 2</div>
    <div class="added">
        <div class="option1">some value</div>
        <div class="option1">some value</div>
        <div class="option1">some value</div>
        <div class="option2">some value</div>
        <div class="option3">some value</div>
        <div class="option3">some value</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="object">
    <div class="object-title">Object Title 2</div>
    <div class="added">
        <div class="option2">some value</div>
        <div class="option2">some value</div>
        <div class="option2">some value</div>
        <div class="option1">some value</div>
        <div class="option3">some value</div>
        <div class="option3">some value</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Example jQuery:**

```
$('.object').each(function(i, obj){
    var object = {}
    object['title'] = $(this).find('.object-title').html();

    //Get each value for option 1 for this object: 

    //Get each value for option 2 for this object:

    //Get each value for option 3 for this object:

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simpler way/what I intended:

```
$('.object').each(function(i, obj){
    var object = {}
    object['title'] = $(this).find('.object-title').html();

    //Get each value for option 1 for this object: 

    $(this).find('.option1').each(function(i, obj){
        //Do stuff
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var object = [];
$('.object').each(function(i, obj){
    object[i] = {};
    object[i]['title'] = $(obj).find('.object-title').html();
    for(j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
        var options = [];
        $(obj).find('.option' + j).each(function(i, obj){
            options[i] = $(obj).html();
        });
        object[i]['option' + j] = options;
    }
});
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of values like

```js
$('.object').each(function(i, obj) {
  var object = {}
  object['title'] = $(this).find('.object-title').html();

  $(this).find('.added > div').each(function() {
    var array = object[this.className];
    if (!array) {
      object[this.className] = array = [];
    }
    array.push($(this).html())
  })

  snippet.log(JSON.stringify(object));
  console.log(object)
});
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="object">
  <div class="object-title">Object Title 2</div>
  <div class="added">
    <div class="option1">some value1</div>
    <div class="option1">some value</div>
    <div class="option1">some value</div>
    <div class="option2">some value2</div>
    <div class="option3">some value</div>
    <div class="option3">some value3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="object">
  <div class="object-title">Object Title 2</div>
  <div class="added">
    <div class="option2">some value</div>
    <div class="option2">some value</div>
    <div class="option2">some value</div>
    <div class="option1">some value</div>
    <div class="option3">some value</div>
    <div class="option3">some value</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the jQuery `.map()` method is king of operations like these:

```js
var object = $('.object').map(function(i,v) {
    var obj = new Object();
    obj.title = $('.object-title', v).text();
    obj.option1 = $('.added .option1', v).map(function() { return this.textContent; }).get().join(',');
    obj.option2 = $('.added .option2', v).map(function() { return this.textContent; }).get().join(',');
    obj.option3 = $('.added .option3', v).map(function() { return this.textContent; }).get().join(',');
    return obj;
}).get();

console.log( JSON.stringify( object ) );
/* OUTPUT:
[{
    "title": "Object Title 2",
    "option1": "some value,some value,some value",
    "option2": "some value",
    "option3": "some value,some value"
}, {
    "title": "Object Title 2",
    "option1": "some value",
    "option2": "some value,some value,some value",
    "option3": "some value,some value"
}]
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="object">
    <div class="object-title">Object Title 2</div>
    <div class="added">
        <div class="option1">some value</div>
        <div class="option1">some value</div>
        <div class="option1">some value</div>
        <div class="option2">some value</div>
        <div class="option3">some value</div>
        <div class="option3">some value</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="object">
    <div class="object-title">Object Title 2</div>
    <div class="added">
        <div class="option2">some value</div>
        <div class="option2">some value</div>
        <div class="option2">some value</div>
        <div class="option1">some value</div>
        <div class="option3">some value</div>
        <div class="option3">some value</div>
    </div>
</div>
```